# SQL Server : syntax error every 5 lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this script in SQL Server

```
BEGIN TRAN; 
    ALTER TABLE [temp_application_params].[APP_ACCOUNTING_UNIT]
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_APP_ACCOUNTING_UNIT_temp PRIMARY KEY (SRG_KEY)
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [temp_application_params].[APP_APPLIC_STATUS_MOTIVATION]
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_APP_APPLIC_STATUS_MOTIVATION_temp PRIMARY KEY (SRG_KEY)
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [temp_application_params].[APP_AREA]
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_APP_AREA_temp PRIMARY KEY (SRG_KEY)
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [temp_application_params].[APP_ASSET_TYPE]
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_APP_ASSET_TYPE_temp PRIMARY KEY (SRG_KEY)
    GO
    ......
```

And I obtain as output

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
>       .....

i.e. there is a syntax error every 5 lines. What is the problem ?

Comment: the `GO`s inside your transaction

Comment: Have I to remove them ?

Comment: Why are u using Go within transaction ? Remove that  and it would work.

Comment: @CodeDecode -- my guess is the sql server mgmt studio auto-generation includes them, and he just copy/pasted.

Comment: Well ALTER TABLE are DDLs and are not "transactionable".... So why have "BEGIN TRAN" at all ?

Comment: @MarcoPolo your comment is NOT correct. DDL statements work just fine in a transaction. Try it and you will see.

Comment: I stand corrected. My Oracle heritage has caught on to me. Sorry.

Comment: I am not too familiar with Oracle. Are DDL statements really not valid in transactions in Oracle? That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using brackets in TSQL []

```
ALTER TABLE temp_application_params.APP_ACCOUNTING_UNIT ADD [CONSTRAINT K_APP_ACCOUNTING_UNIT_temp PRIMARY KEY(SRG_KEY)]
```